# How to use several unique animations one after other in a smart way

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

**Friends, I am using a simple code for you to better understand the focus of the question.**

I have a red box, and want to do some animations with it in a 'timeline', what I meant is anime first one way, then another, then another and so on.

There is a right way to do this? Is there any plugin that makes animations one after the other with a beautiful code, clean and not stupid like this:

```js
(function($) {

  var box = $('.box');

  $(box).animate({
    left: '125',
  });
  
  $(box).animate({
    top: '100'
  })
  
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Can i create a timeline??

In the real code i have more them 40 animations, one after the other, and is very polluted.

I'm using like this:

```
var timeLine = {
  firstAnimation: function() {
    $('element').animate({
      // do whatever i want
    }, TIME, function() {
      // CALL THE SECOND!
      timeLine.secondAnimation();
    });
  },

  secondAnimation: function() {
    // AND SO ON..
  }
};
```

I'm separating the animations functions within my object called Timeline, so it is more readable, but still is pretty ugly and I think I may be doing the wrong way.

I can not use CSS3.

Note: If this case is the most correct way of doing, now I understand why CSS3 animations there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach with the timeline example is a *data-driven* approach.

In my opinion, data-driven approaches are ***wonderful*** and they are a valid software pattern. It basically puts your logic in the data-structure and your code handles the structure.

This is good because it allows for dumb code and smart data-structures. In this scenario, maintenance/debugging is far easier.

To read more, [*The Art of Unix Programming*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131429019)(which is a book about more than unix) has a whole chapter dedicated to this approach.

Now, having said that, there can be an improvement made to your timeline approach

1. Switch from an object to an array composed of `JSON` objects
2. Have the current animation index stored in a variable
3. Make a recursive function that calls itself until the animations have completed

---

```
var timeLineAnimations = [{
    element: 'some-selector',
    animation: {
        top: '100'
    },
    time: 1000
}, {
    element: 'some-selector',
    animation: {
        left: '100'
    },
    time: 2000
}, ...];

var currentIndex = 0;

function animateTimeLine(currentIndex) {
    var currentAnimation = timeLineAnimations[currentIndex];

    $(currentAnimation.element).animate(currentAnimation.animation, currentAnimation.time, function() {
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex < timeLineAnimations.length) {
            animateTimeLine(currentIndex);
        }
    });
}
animateTimeline(0);
```

The benefit of this improvement is it is purely data-driven and you no longer have named functions like `firstAnimation`, `secondAnimation`, etc.

All the code does is mechanically call itself and your logic **is** the data-structure

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what i'm looking for @AmmarCSE!!!.. And thanks, i'm going to buy the book.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari, no problem. I hope you enjoy it.(not all chapters are relevant to software patterns, so just giving you  a heads up)

Comment: No problem, i like everything related with technology, programming, etc. Currently i'm reading the javascript patterns by stoyan stefanov, very good!